# Show fields(textbox and labels) based on value from dropdown list

Tags: javascript, html

I have a dropdown with a selected value by default. My idea is to load the fields when that value is on the default selected. How do I make that? I'm trying to use onload on the div but I have little knowledge in javascript.

Here is my javascript code

```
function check()
{
    $(document).ready(function() 
    {  
        if($('#status').val() == 'Cancelled' || $('#status').val() == 'Hold')
        {
            $('#prf').show();
            $('#lblreason').show();
            $('#lbldate').show();   
            $('#reason').show();
            $('#date').show();
            if($('#status').val() == 'Cancelled')
           {
            document.getElementById("lblreason").innerHTML = "Cancellation Reason";
            document.getElementById("lbldate").innerHTML = "Date of Cancellation";
           }    

            if($('#status').val() == 'Hold')
           {
            document.getElementById("lblreason").innerHTML = "Hold Reason";
            document.getElementById("lbldate").innerHTML = "Date of Hold";
           }  
        }
        else
        {
            $('#prf').hide();
            $('#lblreason').hide();
            $('#lbldate').hide();   
            $('#reason').hide();      
            $('#date').hide();
        }
    }
}
```

HTML

```
<div id = "prf" onload="check()" style ="display:none;">

            <label class='listnames' id ='lblreason' style = 'width:150px; '></label>
            <input type='text' name = 'status_reason' value = '<?=$status_reason?>' id ='reason' class='required-fields' style = ""/>
            <label class='listnames' id ='date' style ='width:150px; '></label>
            <input type='date' id ='lbldate' name='status_date' placeholder='mm/dd/yyyy' autocomplete='off' value ='<?=$status_date?>' style='height: 24px; ' class='required-fields'>

            </div>

<select class="required-fields" id = "status" name="status" onload="check()" <?php if($prf_status == "Served") { echo "disabled"; } ?> >
                <option value = "Outstanding" <?php if($prf_status == "Outstanding") { echo "selected = 'selected'"; } ?> >Outstanding</option>
                <option value = "Served" disabled <?php if($prf_status == "Served") { echo "selected = 'selected'"; } ?> >Served</option>
                <option value = "Cancelled" <?php if($prf_status == "Cancelled") { echo "selected = 'selected'"; } ?> >Cancelled</option>
                <option value = "Hold" <?php if($prf_status == "Hold") { echo "selected = 'selected'"; } ?> >Hold</option>
            </select>
```

Comment: Remove `onload` from div also discard the `check()` moving its contents outside the body.

Comment: Done that but nothing changed

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `onload` on `div`.

You just need to "pull out" the code in the `check` function.

```js
//function check()
//{
    $(document).ready(function() {  
        if($('#status').val() == 'Cancelled' || $('#status').val() == 'Hold')
        {
            $('#prf').show();
            $('#lblreason').show();
            $('#lbldate').show();   
            $('#reason').show();
            $('#date').show();
            if($('#status').val() == 'Cancelled')
           {
            document.getElementById("lblreason").innerHTML = "Cancellation Reason";
            document.getElementById("lbldate").innerHTML = "Date of Cancellation";
           }    

            if($('#status').val() == 'Hold')
           {
            document.getElementById("lblreason").innerHTML = "Hold Reason";
            document.getElementById("lbldate").innerHTML = "Date of Hold";
           }  
        }
        else
        {
            $('#prf').hide();
            $('#lblreason').hide();
            $('#lbldate').hide();   
            $('#reason').hide();      
            $('#date').hide();
        }
    });
//}
```

Comment: Tried it nothing happened.

Comment: Of course. This fiddle is not support `php` so I can't give you working fiddle. It's just show you what you need to do with **your** code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this example, using change event:

```js
$(function() {
  var prf = $('#prf'), lblreason = $('#lblreason'), lbldate = $('#lbldate');
  var funcMap = {};
  funcMap.Outstanding = function(){
    prf.hide();
  };
  funcMap.Cancelled = funcMap.Hold = function(text) {
    prf.show();
    lblreason.text(text + ' Reason');
    lbldate.text('Date of ' + text);
  };
  $('#status').on('change', function(e) {
    var val = this.value;
    funcMap[val](val);
  }).trigger('change');//on page load
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="prf">
  <label id='lblreason'></label>
  <input type='text' id='reason' />
  <label id='lbldate'></label>
  <input type='date' id='date' placeholder='mm/dd/yyyy'>
</div>

<select id="status">
  <option>Outstanding</option>
  <option disabled=''>Served</option>
  <option>Cancelled</option>
  <option>Hold</option>
</select>
```